# Get string with document.querySelector starting from 2nd character

Tags: javascript, dom, queryselector

I have the following html span element:

```
<span class="percent">-20%</span>
```

To access the DOM element and then get the string value inside I'm using the query selector command:

```
document.querySelector('span.percent').innerText;
```

And I'm getting `-20%` string. How do I get the string value only starting from second character? I other words to get `20%`.

Comment: [MDN String#slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)